# Getting unnecessary information back from MongoDB query using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to query a local database and have tried:
(Assume `cardName` is defined)

`const card = await Card.findOne({ name: cardName }, 'name art description')`

`const card = await Card.findOne({ name: cardName }, { name: 1,art: 1,description: 1 })`

`const card = await Card.findOne({ name: cardName }).project('name art description')`

`const card = await Card.findOne({ name: cardName }, 'name art description').exec()`

Even though I get the fields I specify I also get other unnecessary fields such as

```js
$__schema: [object Object]
collection: [object Object]
$collection: [object Object]
$__originalValidate: function(pathsToValidate, options, callback) { if (typeof pathsToValid . . .
$__save: function() { var _context = context || this; _this.wrap(name, fn, _context, Array.from(arguments), options); }
$__validate: function() { var _context = context || this; _this.wrap(name, fn, _context, Array.from(arguments), options); }
$__remove: function() { var _context = context || this; _this.wrap(name, fn, _context, Array.from(arguments), options); }
$__deleteOne: function() { process.nextTick(() => fn.apply(this, arguments)); }
$__init: function syncWrapper() { kareem.execPreSync(name, this, arguments); var toReturn = fn.apply(this, arguments); kareem.execPostSync(name, this, [toReturn]); return toReturn; }
$isMongooseModelPrototype: true
$__handleSave: function(options, callback) . . .
```

How do I ensure that I only get the fields I specify and NOT any of the unnecessary information?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`lean()`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) function on your query. From the docs:

> Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain
> javascript objects, not Mongoose Documents. They have no save method,
> getters/setters, virtuals, or other Mongoose features.

```
const docs = await Model.find().lean();
```